# How to load angular app and modules for dynamic html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, requirejs

Here I meet an issue when use angularjs to load app or modules from a dynamic html elements:

$(document. body).html('<div ng-app="rootApp"><div ng-controller="inputCrlr">......</div></div>');

require(['angular'],function(angular){

angular. module('rootApp',[]);

});

It shows rootApp isn't available error log when requirejs load angularjs before invoke callback function of require.

Comment: I haven't go around with such a requirement before, but what happens when you `require` before and then do `$(document.body).html('...');` ?

Comment: don't use `ng-app` and bootstrap angular manually once all dependencies are loaded

Comment: Thanks, after remove ng-app and use bootstrap to manually load modules, it is running properly

Comment: It will return the same error as angular will load ngapp elements when its js file is loaded

Comment: still issue exists??

Comment: Yes, it was solved